# Write output to file

Tags: ruby

I have Ruby code similar to:

```
ok.rb
hasil = "input operator salah"
 puts hasil

exec("sort ok.rb > output.txt") if fork.nil?
```

It just wrote all code into `output.txt`. However, I only want `hasil` result to be written to `output.txt`. How should I modify the code for such an end result?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You've executed the `sort` command taking `ok.rb` as the *input*. Instead, you want to run `ok.rb` and take its *output* as the input to sort.

Without knowing Ruby, I'd expect this to be something like:

```
exec("ruby ok.rb | sort > output.txt") if fork.nil?
```

I've just tried this from my Linux desktop and it worked fine:

ok.rb:

```
hasil = "input operator salah"
puts hasil
```

other.rb:

```
exec("ruby ok.rb | sort > output.txt") if fork.nil?
```

Execute:

```
$ ruby other.rb
$ cat output.txt
input operator salah
```

(You've only provided a single line of output so there wasn't exactly a lot to sort.)

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way would be to change the preceding code to not produce output to stdout directly, but instead to only build the string and then sort this from ruby and print it to the file. Like this for example:

```
hasil = "input operator salah"

File.open("output.txt", "w") do |f|
  f.puts hasil.split("\n").sort.join("\n")
end
```

If replacing unix sort with ruby sort is not an option (maybe because sort was just an example and in reality you're piping to a different application that can't easily be replaced with ruby), you can write your code to the application directly instead of writing to stdout. You could even write your code to be general enough to write to any IO.

```
def generate_output(out)
  hasil = "input operator salah"
  out.puts hasil
end

# If you decide to output the text directly to stdout (without sorting)
generate_output(stdout)

# If you instead want to pipe to sort:
IO.popen("sort > output.txt", "w") do |sort|
  generate_output(sort)
end
```